# A question regarding to the badge

Tags: iphone

I  have

NSDictionary *dictionary =

{"aps":
  {"alert":"This is a Push Message sent from Server!",
    "badge":60
  }
}

I  have  only 1  question

I  need 60 from this NSDictionary into NString.

Comment: Is that really an `NSDictionary` or just an `NSString`/`NSData` received from Apple?

Answer (score 2):

You can just get the NSNumber and format it as a string, something along the lines of:

```
NSDictionary *aps = [dictionary objectForKey:@"aps"];
NSNumber *num = [aps objectForKey:@"badge"];
NSString *numStr = [num stringValue];
```